# Assigning variable comparisons to if/else statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using a conditional statement that returns a result based on when a user clicks during a video.

Currently I have fixed comparison values as I only had one video but now I  am adding more videos I want to make those values variable depending on which video is being played. Each video will have a different time for each chapter

```
//currently fixed values for one video    
$('#response').on('click', function() {
      var mycurrentTime = myVid.currentTime;
        if (mycurrentTime < 20) { //can '20' become "x"?
          result = "chapter 1" ;
        } else if (mycurrentTime < 40) {//can '40' become "y"?
          result = "chapter 2" ;
        } else {
          result = "chapter 3" ;
        }
```

After completing the first video the user clicks to move to the next video which changes the video tag contents using innerHTML method.

```
document.getElementById("videoElement").innerHTML = '<source src="video2.mp4">';
```

I'm not sure if this is feasible but I was hoping for something like adding an "id=vid1" to the video source tags so if #vid1 then x=25 y=47. What is the best way to assign values for each video and chapters and allocate them to the conditional statement?

Comment: Use [`data` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) to store the metadata in the `video` element, then read them back out when `#response` is clicked

Comment: Thanks for the link. I haven't learnt about data attributes yet so I'll investigate further and try to solve my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to use `data` attributes.

```
document.getElementById("videoElement").innerHTML = '<source src="video2.mp4" data-x="25" data-y="25">';
```

to get the value:

```
document.getElementById("videoElement").getAttribute('data-x');
```

to set the value:

```
document.getElementById("videoElement").setAttribute('data-x', val);
```

Comment: `.setAttribute('data-x', val)`*

Comment: Better still, use `dataset`. See MDN [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) and [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/dataset)

Comment: Considering he uses jQuery I would recommend to use `('#videoElement').data('x', value);`